# while consuming wcf getting exception

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, windows-phone-8

i am consuming a wcf service from my wp8 app i am getting communicationexception 
following is screenshot of exception

[image]

following is the code of consumption of wcf

```
 ServiceReference1.Service1Client sclient;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


                sclient = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client(new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://192.168.1.127:80/Service1.svc"));


           // var mobileDataService = new MobileDataServiceClient(new MobileDataServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration(), new EndpointAddress(address));
            UserDetails info = new UserDetails();
            info.Id = 2323;
            sclient.InsertUserDetailsAsync(info);
           // sclient.InsertUserDetailsCompleted += sclient_InsertUserDetailsCompleted; ;


            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        void sclient_InsertUserDetailsCompleted(object sender, InsertUserDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("completed");
            this.res.Text = e.Result;
        }
```

Comment: can you catch the exception and print the call stack?

Comment: @AndyH  i placed try-catch but its not getting the sacktrace

Comment: first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.ni.dl

Comment: then print through Trace.TraceError(e.ToString()). e.Message is not enough, e.ToString will give you call stack. And surely you need a trace listener in config to output the trace ideally to a log file.